# I need 24 inch monitor LED with the following specs

Tags: monitors, led

1. Full HD
2. 1920 1080
3. Have internal speaker ( do not need additional speaker to hear sounds)
4. Price around $100 (cheaper better)
5. Size around 24 inch.
6. Support HDMI

I've been searching for it in tokopedia and many specs aren't clear. Many "full hd" monitors are actually HD ready.

One thing that may qualify is this monitor

https://www.tokopedia.com/utamaglodok/lg-led-tv-24-inch-full-hd-24tk42-garansi-resmi-lg?whid=9811

It's LG LED 24tk42

However, I cannot find the actual LG website that list the specs. There is the spec for LG 24TK4225 and those are HD ready and not full HD

I wonder if there is a site to compare specs for LED or if someone knows the exact item I can buy

Comment: Full HD, 1080p, and 1920x1080 mean the exact same thing. "HD Ready" is another thing, relating to whether the screen can accept HD signals. (It's a spec about the connectivity, not the panel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
These are top picks around 100$
```

1. [HP 24mh FHD Monitor - Computer Monitor with 23.8-inch IPS Display (1080p) - Built-in Speakers and VESA Mounting - Height/Tilt Adjustment for Ergonomic Viewing - HDMI and DisplayPort - (1D0J9AA#ABA)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BF4CZSV)

FHD with built in speakers

```
The below ones are without speakers but have audio Jack
```

1. [Philips 246E9QDSB 24" frameless monitor, Full HD IPS, 129% sRGB, 75Hz, FreeSync, VESA, 4Yr Advance Replacement Warranty](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CK4W58Y)

FHD with audio jack for headphones.

2. [Sceptre 24 Inch Ultra Thin Ultra Slim 1080P 75Hz LED Monitor HDMI VGA, Metal Black (E248W-1920R)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HIA63AU)